# Why protected set for one to many relationship property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have Customer and Order entities. While defining the class for customer using fluent hibernate, why do we need to specify "protected set" for Orders list property.

```
public virtual IList<Order> Orders { get; protected set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not required to specify `protected` on setter. It's just a good design to do so.

If no access modifier is specified on setter, it will implicitly have the same access modifier as the property itself (`public` in your case). When setter is public, any consumer of your class could modify the `Orders` property and set it to another instance.

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

var customer = new Customer();
customer.Orders = new List<Order>();
```

When you define `protected` access modifier on setter, only the inherited class will be able to modify the property. To any other consumers, the `Orders` property appears as read-only. This is effectively an [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

NHibernate uses lazy-loading by default. It's a technique where some properties (usually lists) are not loaded immediately, but on the first usage. NHibernate implements this with proxies. A proxy class, which is dynamically created, inherits from your `Entity` class and overrides all of it's properties. That's the reason you have `virtual` on all your class members.

And, to get to the point, when you define `protected set` you are allowing NHibernate's dynamic proxy to modify your `Orders` property. `Orders` could be initialized to some empty proxy collection and when someone tries to read it, a database load will be triggered and `Orders` property will be replaced with a list of Order instances loaded from the database.

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual IList<Order> Orders { get; protected set; }
}

var customer = new Customer();
//customer.Orders = new List<Order>(); // error: can't modify property

var orderCount = customer.Orders.Count; // this will trigger lazy-loading
```